# How do I find a chat I took part in?

Tags: support, chat

I recently chatted with another user on Stack Overflow and would like to have a look at that chat again.

What search mechanism can I use to find that chat?

Comment: [This one](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201113/discussion-between-carlspring-and-jf-meier)?